# How do I redirect my front-end (Angular) application based on the result from another server

Tags: angular, spring-boot, angular8

I have URL ex. abc.com/myapp, when hit on this URL it will go to another domain do the login process, after the success full login this results will come to my server context path 'myapp' through headers. Based on the header result my back-end will identify the user and return some Json to the abc.com/myapp front end. How to receive this Json to the base path 'myapp'

Comment: This URL might help https://medium.com/better-programming/setup-a-proxy-for-api-calls-for-your-angular-cli-app-6566c02a8c4d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood, it is something similar to the OAuth process. As it will redirect the user to the URL that was requested before login.

Is there an option to create an API to get this JSON after the user is authenticated and redirected to the desired destination? So after the App is loaded, the App can send a request to the server and get the JSON needed (Like a User Profile or so on).